# Rust BubbleSort WebAssembly, wasm_bindgen not exported properly (wbg)

Tags: rust, module, webassembly, bubble-sort, wasm-bindgen

I'm having trouble loading the webassembly file with the sorting function and it displays this error:

```
TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="wbg" error: module is not an object or function
```

Compiles code:

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn bubble_sort(arr: &mut [i32]) {
    let mut swapped = true;
    while swapped {
        swapped = false;
        for i in 1..arr.len() {
            if arr[i - 1] > arr[i] {
                arr.swap(i - 1, i);
                swapped = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```js
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(
    fetch("./wasm_example_bindgen_bg.wasm"),
        {}
  ).then((wa) => {
    console.log(wa.instance.exports.bubble_sort([10,11]));
});
```

What might be the problem with?
version:
wasm-bindgen-cli  0.2.74
rust 1.67

I am trying to make a sorting application with bubble sorting.

Comment: can you share a reproducer ? I dont know much about wasm and how to generate the error you get.